# react component detect changes only after a refresh

Tags: reactjs

**Navbar.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { useHistory } from 'react-router'
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useState } from 'react'

const Navbar = () => {
    let history = useHistory()
    let [token, setToken] = useState('')

    const logout = () => {
        setToken(window.localStorage.removeItem('token'))
        history.push('/login')
    }
    
    useEffect(() => {
        setToken(window.localStorage.getItem('token'))
    })

    return (
        <nav>
            <div className='nav-content'>
                <h1>LunCare <i class="fas fa-plus"></i></h1>   

                {
                token !== null ?
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href='' onClick={logout}>Logout</a>
                    </li>
                </ul> 
                :
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href='/register'>Register</a>
                        <a href='/login'>Login</a>
                    </li>
                </ul> 
                }
            </div>
        </nav>
    )
}

export default Navbar
```

**Login.js (I dont think this is needed but ill include it)**

```
import React from 'react'
import { useHistory } from 'react-router'

const Login = () => {
    let user = {
        username: '',
        password: ''
    }

    let error = false

    let history = useHistory()
    
    const login = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(user)
      }).then(res => {
          if(res.status === 200 || res.status === 201) {
                return res.json()
          } else {
                error = true
          }
      })
        .then(data => {
    
        window.localStorage.setItem('token', data.token);
        history.push('/')
      })
        .catch(err => {

        })
      
    }
    
    const updateForm = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        user[e.target.name] = e.target.value
    }

    return (
        <div className='form-container'>
            <form onSubmit={login}>
                <div className='form-content'>
                    <h1>Log In</h1>
                    <label>Name</label>
                    <input type='text' name='username' onChange={updateForm}></input>
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type='password' name='password' onChange={updateForm}></input>
                    <button type='submit'>Log In</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Login
```

> Everything works as intended, but when I successfully login the navbar doesnt change accordingly... I need to refresh it so that it detects the token, how can I make it so that the navbar changes when the user gets redirected after logging in, any help is appreciated!

Comment: useEffect(() => {
        setToken(window.localStorage.getItem('token'))
    })
Pretty sure that you are doing an infinite rerender inside here. set it to     useEffect(() => {
        setToken(window.localStorage.getItem('token'))
    }, []). The , [] part will make sure you only fetch the token once. Are you unmouning the navbar on logout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Move the `token` to a common parent component say `Parent` that renders, `Nav` and `Login`.
2. Inside `Parent` should you declare the state, `token`.
3. Pass the setter `token` function to `Login`, use that on your login handler function

```js
// Login.js
...
const Login = ({ setToken }) => { // destructure `setToken`
   const login = (e) => {
        ...
        .then(data => {
    
        window.localStorage.setItem('token', data.token);
        setToken(data.token); // set the token here
        history.push('/')
      })
        .catch(err => {

        })
      ...
    }
}
```

4. Pass both `token` and `setToken` to your `Nav` component

```js
const Navbar = ({ token, setToken }) => { // destructure token and setToken here
...
    // let [token, setToken] = useState('')  // don't need this

    const logout = () => {
        window.localStorage.removeItem('token')
        setToken(null) // need to clear state after logging out
        history.push('/login')
    }
    
    /* Don't need this either
    useEffect(() => {
        setToken(window.localStorage.getItem('token'))
    })
    */
...
}
```